# automate image upload from windows explore with selenium and AutoIT

Tags: selenium, autoit

I have to automate a scenario like a upload an image from windows explorer to TinyMCE component using Selenium. Since Selenium does not support OS control, I used AutoIt to upload the image. 
AutiIt sets the image path to "File name" and seems like it clicks on 'Open' button as well. But the image is not loading to my "source" field.

Here is my Selenium command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/XXXXX/src/test/resources/uploadImage.exe");
// Path of the AutoIT script file
```

AutoIT script:

```
WinActivate("Open")
Send("C:\LCNGProjects\Screenshots\Images\GifImage1.gif")
Sleep(5000)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Refer the attached screenshot

[image: Refer the attached screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I have got the questions correct, Did you compile the script.

Can you please go through link below for script compilation and step by step info how to upload a file.

https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use AutoIt. Auto will make your script dependable on windows machine only.

Instead of it find element using locator(i.e. xpath) of upload button which is having tag as `type="file"`. Now pass this simple sendKeys with absolute path of your image in your machine like below:-

```
button2.sendKeys("C:\\UsersDesktop\\logo\\Summit-Logo-900px.png");
```

Or use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Append the path of file exluding your project path and filename inside your project
Example :-

```
button.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\logo\\Summit-Logo-900px.png");
```

below link contains more option to upload file like below :-

- Using SendKeys command.
- Using AutoIt scripting.
- Using Jacob com    interface.

http://www.techbeamers.com/handle-file-upload-selenium-webdriver/#h3

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to add full source code here. You can call the AutoIT script using this command inside your test case.

```
// Call to AutoIT script to upload the image

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\xxxxx\\src\\test\\resources\\uploadImage.exe");
```

**AutoIT Scrip**

```
 ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
    ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\xxxx\Images\jpgImage")
    ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

For more information refer the following link
https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html